# How to match a network over multiple frequencies?

Tags: passive-networks, impedance-matching

I'm trying to match the following network using the Matching Network Designer so that the resistance curves (solid lines) get pulled towards the horizontal  line and the reactance curves (dotted lines) get pulled towards the  line.[image]

I was trying to use the MATLAB Matching Network Designer except it only seems to work for a single frequency (and single load and source impedance). I need something where I can specify multiple instances of this across the entire broadband spectrum.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: What specific complex impedance are you trying to match to what other complex (or resistive) impedance and how do both (or one) vary with frequency?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to match the red lines representing the resistive and reactive components of an antenna system (solid is real(Z) and dotted is im(Z) to a 50+j0 Ohm source (i.e. the transmitter)